# How do you set the ESP32 to maximum BLE Power?

Tags: esp32, arduino-esp32

How do you increase the ESP32 BLE to maximum power, for maximum distance?  It appears the default is set to index 5, which is only +3dbm.  (ESP_PWR_LVL_P3 = index 5, Corresponding to +3dbm) [More Details](https://docs.espressif.com/projects/esp-idf/en/v4.1/api-reference/bluetooth/controller_vhci.html)

Answer (score 2):

There used to be a [bug](https://github.com/nkolban/esp32-snippets/issues/939), it appears its fixed now.  As indicated above, ESP_PWR_LVL_P9 = index 7, which indicates +9dbm.

After "BLEDevice::init("ESP32");", add this to get the maximum output:

```
esp_ble_tx_power_set(ESP_BLE_PWR_TYPE_DEFAULT, ESP_PWR_LVL_P9); 
esp_ble_tx_power_set(ESP_BLE_PWR_TYPE_ADV, ESP_PWR_LVL_P9);
esp_ble_tx_power_set(ESP_BLE_PWR_TYPE_SCAN ,ESP_PWR_LVL_P9);
```

Check via this:

```
int pwrAdv  = esp_ble_tx_power_get(ESP_BLE_PWR_TYPE_ADV);
int pwrScan = esp_ble_tx_power_get(ESP_BLE_PWR_TYPE_SCAN);
int pwrDef  = esp_ble_tx_power_get(ESP_BLE_PWR_TYPE_DEFAULT);
Serial.println("Power Settings: (ADV,SCAN,DEFAULT)");         //all should show index7, aka +9dbm
Serial.println(pwrAdv);
Serial.println(pwrScan);
Serial.println(pwrDef);
```

Can also confirm via an Android phone app like nRF Connect, that the Tx Power Level is now 9dBm.